# What is Normalization across samples and Normalization across genes mean?

Tags: normalization, computational-statistics

Can anyone tell me what does normalization across samples and normalization across genes mean statistically. What is the exact difference between the both?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I would hazard a guess and say that with across samples you will be normalising each sample so that each one is N(0,1), and similar for genes. This will mean that you can compare each samples to see if the genes have a similar composition, and vice-versa for genes.